# Contrary interpretations of Least Squares for Regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression

According to the original thought, our goal is to minimize the quadratic error $$\min\{\frac{1}{2}(Ax-b)^2 \}$$
Then, we search the extremum by the derivation of $x$ $$A^T(Ax-b)=0$$ $$A^TAx=A^Tb$$  $$x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$
This is the classical interpretation of Least Square, with a little pic by myself:
[image]

Furthermore, there is another interpretation according to the lecture of Prof. STRANG, which indicates that we are looking for the projection from $b$ to the column space of $A$ instead of $b$:  $$p=Ax=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$
with the projection matrix:  $$A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$
Then, we get another new interpretation with the pic:
[image]
These are two different interpretations of Least Square, with however same formulation. So, I am confused. Why could this happen? Which interpretation is right? And Why?

Comment: "Least Squares" is a generic name for a mathematical technic of optimisation or adjustment. This process can be applied to various problems in many different circonstances. So, one have to specify what we are talking about: Saying "Least Squares" is not sufficient. It is ambiguous until we specify to what case it is applied.

Comment: I specified it by regression in the title

Comment: The second one looks more like PCA than regression...

Comment: @HenriSHI : One have to specify the criteria : it is not the same if the criteria of least mean squares is relative to the vertical distances between the points and the line or if it is the orthogonal distances between the points and the line, or what ever other criterion.

Comment: @JJacquelin : The 2 criteria you give exactly derive the same formula of $x$. However, according to the picture, the $x$ has drifted. That is weird.

Comment: If the critéria is defined as the least mean squares of the vertical distances between the points and the straight line, the LMS regression leads to a first result y=a*x+b


If the critéria is defined as the least mean squares of the orthogonal distances between the points and the straight line, the LMS regression leads to a second result y=c*x+d

If the critéria is defined as the least mean squares of the horizontal distances between the points and the straight line, the LMS regression leads to a third result y=p*x+q

Comment: Each different criteria leads to a different result i.e. a different straight line. Your figure is false if you draw the same line in case of two different criteria. That is why the question is ambiguous if the wording do not give all the informations allowing to define the right criteria corresponding to the problem.

Comment: A good explanation is available at : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html

Answer (score 1):

Both interpretations are correct.

The only thing that is NOT correct is *your* interpretation that the column space of $A$ must be the same straight line of your first picture.

**EDIT.** They cannot give different values of $x$, because $x$ is the same in both intepretations.

First one: $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$.

Second one: $x$ is the solution of the linear system $Ax = b$, when you replace $b$ by $p=Ax=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$.

Ok, do it: $Ax = p =A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb $.

Isn't $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ a solution of this system?

Comment: Yes, I exactly mean the same straight line in the first picture. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Nope. It's not. For instance, because the column space of $A$ needs not to be of dimension one. And also because it has nothing to do.

Comment: I see.. it is merely an example.

Comment: Well, I am still absessed by the two interpretations. They give different values of $x$

Comment: Nope. They don't. And nope: it's not an example. Both straight lines are unrelated: forget about it.

Comment: The point is that they have same formula for $x$, while the positon of $x$ has drifted according to the second picture. That is what confuses me.

Comment: Forget your second picture: it has nothing to do with the problem.